# Export a django model in .xls

Tags: django, excel, python-2.7

How can I export a whole model filled with data (around 15 columns and 2500 rows) into an excel file to download it directly with a button in a html page?

This is my model:

```
class Cleartobill(models.Model):
    soss = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    soss_line = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    build_date = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    ctb_Status = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    ctb_comment = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sjz_status = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    production_result_Code = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    bu = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pf = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    current_fcd = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    tan = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    eta = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
    tied = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    otm_status = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    bucket_aged = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    ead = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: in modeladmin or in your own views?

Comment: yeah I need a logic that can be triggered in views.py so I can add a button into my template and users can download the data directly from that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39773908/export-a-django-model-in-xls Might be of help

Comment: there are a lot of options depending on your needs. is simple csv enough? do you need multiple sheets or colors? should the result be an xslx? you will end up with a view that includes the logic... oh and there is `django-import-export` which adds those functionalities to the admin and will by chance provide an API you can use in your view. `xslxwriter` is also an option you should check.

Comment: At the end I want to export the whole data from the model and maybe modify the column title (bold) and hide some column. that's all, which you may think is my best option for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize your model objects to json by [django serializers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/serialization/) and then, create excel file from it by a tool like [tablib](https://github.com/kennethreitz/tablib)